# getter using pinia and vue3 undefined

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, pinia

I have not been able to get the getters from Pinia integrate correclty into  my vue3 project.
So i have a index.js, getters.js and the file file where i want to fetch the getter test.js

my index,js looks like this:

```
import * as actions from './actions'
import * as getters from './getters'
export const usevwoStore = defineStore('vwoStore', {
  state: () => {
    return {
      groups:[],
    }
  },
  actions: actions.actions,
  getters: getters.getters
})

if (import.meta.hot) {
  import.meta.hot.accept(acceptHMRUpdate(usevwoStore, import.meta.hot))
  /*import.meta.hot.accept((newModule) => {
    if (newModule) {
      console.log('updated: count is now ', newModule.count)
    }
  })*/
}

export default usevwoStore
```

**my getters.js looks like this:**

```
// import { aanwezighedenSecundairHelperService } from './../../services/aanwezigheden-secundair.service.js'
import { useGlobalStore } from '@/store/store.js';
import { toRaw } from "vue";
import { usevwoStore } from './index.js';
import { restServ } from '@/services/rest.service.js';
import router from '@/router/router.js'

const dateOperations = dateOperationsMix.methods


export const getters = {

 getgroups(){
  return this.usevwoStore.groups
  // console.log('sdfsd')
}
}
```

**and finally where i want to fetch the getters is  my test.js file**

```
import { mapStores, mapWritableState, mapState } from 'pinia'
import { useGlobalStore } from '@/store/store.js'
import { usevwoStore } from '../../store/index.js'
import { toRaw } from "vue";
import { computed } from 'vue'
import { useRoute } from 'vue-router'
import { storeToRefs } from 'pinia'
export default {
  name: "test",
  setup() {
    const myStoreActions = toRaw(useGlobalStore())
    const myStoreState = useGlobalStore()
    const vwoStoreState = usevwoStore()
 const vwoStoreGetters = storeToRefs(usevwoStore())
    const route = useRoute();
    const currentRoute = computed(() => route.path)
    return { myStoreActions, myStoreState,vwoStoreActions,vwoStoreState,route, currentRoute,vwoStoreGetters }
  },

  data () {
    return {}
    
  },
  computed: {
    groups: {
  
      get: function () {    
        **return this.vwoStoreGetters.getgroups;**
      },
      set: function () {
        return this.vwoStoreGetters.getgroups;
      }
    }
....
```

i am always getting this.vwoStoreGetters.getgroups undefined..is teh logic correct what i am using? Does it have to do with the computed property?
Thanks guys!

Comment: It should be this.groups and not this.usevwoStore.groups in getters.js

Comment: thanks you are right, i did tried that. but it seems that if i fetch it directly from the state it works...meaning "selfvwoStoreGetters.getgroups" but dont know what is the difference. the vwoStoreGetters constant acts as a storeToRefs. thanks man